# Sheaf cohomology of the structure sheaf of the grasmannian G(2,7)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, grassmannian

How can I calculate $H^i(Gr(2,7),\mathcal{O}_{Gr(2,7)})$ over the base field $\mathbb{C}$?

Or in general $H^i(Gr(k,n),\mathcal{O}_{Gr(k,n)})$?

The first idea came to my mind is using Plücker embedding $i:Gr(2,7)\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^{20}$ and the long exact sequence associated to the ideal sheaf exact sequence $$0\rightarrow\mathcal{I}_{Gr(2,7)}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{20}}\rightarrow{i_*}\mathcal{O}_{Gr(2,7)}\rightarrow{0}\,.$$

But I don't know how to calculate $H^i(Gr(2,7),\mathcal{I}_{Gr(2,7)})$ either.

Comment: 1. $Gr(k,n)$ is Fano. 2. Use Kodaira vanishing to show $h^{0,i}=0, i>0$ for Fano variety.

Comment: What is the relation between $h^{0,i}$ and $H^i(Gr(k,n),\mathcal{O}_{Gr(k,n)})$?

Comment: $h^{0,i}(X)$ is the dimension of $H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})$, common notation for Hodge number.

Comment: @AGlearner Thank you. I didn't know Kodaira vanishing. Basically what you say is since $\omega_X^*$ (equal to pull back $i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^N}(n)$) is very ample, we can use it in Kodaira vanishing. So we get $0=H^i(X,\omega_X\otimes\omega_X^*)=H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ for $i>0$.

Comment: Yes, another comment: For a smooth projective Fano variety, the anticanonical divisor is ample, but not necessarily very ample (counterexample: del Pezzo surface of degree 2).

Comment: @AGlearner Thank you. I don't know what the usual procedure on this platform but if you post your answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Never mind, sometimes people (including me) just prefer commenting to writing a complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For some reason, my perfectly valid answer was deleted without notifications. More than 5 people said that this does not provide an answer to the question. This is quite surprising as the theorem literally does provide the answer to the question.)

The original answer : this follows from the [Borel-Weil theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Weil%E2%80%93Bott_theorem). Indeed, $L = \mathcal O_{Gr(2,7)}$ is the line bundle associated to the trivial representation. Hence $H^0(X,L) = \mathbb C$ and $H^i(X,L) = 0$ for $i>0$. This works for any flag variety $X = G/P$ where $G$ is a semisimple algebraic group, and $P$ is a parabolic subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Question: "How can I calculate $H^i(Gr(2,7),\mathcal{O}_{Gr(2,7)})$ over the base field $\mathbb{C}$?"

Answer: Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $V:=K^n$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$ and $W \subseteq V$ a $k$-dimensional subspace. You may let $P \subseteq SL(V)$ be the (parabolic) subgroup of elements fixing $W$. There is a "canonical" isomorphism $SL(V)/P \cong G(k,V)$ where $G(k,V)$ is the grassmannian variety of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $V$. If you look in Fulton-Harris book "Representation theory: A first course" in Section 15.4 you will find a relation between global sections of invertible sheaves $\mathcal{L}$ on $G(k,V)$ and $SL(V)$-modules: For any $\mathcal{L} \in Pic(G(k,V))$ it follows $H^i(G(k,V), \mathcal{L})$ is an irreducible $SL(V)$-module. The book also gives explicit formulas for the dimension $h^i(G(k,V), \mathcal{L})$. If $\mathcal{L}:=\mathcal{O}$ is the structur sheaf, the book gives explicit formulas for $h^i(G(k,V), \mathcal{O})$.

Example 1.If $K$ is a field of characteristic zero and of $dim_K(V)=n$, let $G(k,V)$ be the grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces in $V$. There is the Plucker embedding

$$ \rho: G(k,V) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}:=\mathbb{P}(\wedge^k V^*)$$

sending a subspace $W \subseteq V$ to the line $\wedge^k W \subseteq \wedge^k V$. The space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $m$ on $\mathbb{P}$ is the $m$'th symmetric power $Sym^m(\wedge^k V^*)$. Let $I(G)_m$ be the polynomials of degree $m$ vanishing on $G(k,V)$. We get an exact sequence of $SL(V)$-modules

$$0 \rightarrow I(G)_m \rightarrow Sym^m(\wedge^k V^*) \rightarrow W_m \rightarrow 0.$$

In Exercise 15.43 they calculate the $SL(V)$-module $I(G)_2$: $SL(V)$ is a semi simple linear algebraic group and any finite dimensional $SL(V)$-module decompose as a direct sum of irreducible modules. Such a decomposition is given in the exercise. In the book they give an elementary introduction to the representation theory of $SL(V), GL(V),..$ and give explicit and elementary examples from geometry.